# Send mail from asp.net application by unblocking gmail latest security technique

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am developing a registration form in asp.net C#. When clicking on Submit button, I want to sent a email from my gmail account to registered customer's gmail account. But when I tried, a security mail coming as 
"

Hi *****, We recently blocked a sign-in attempt to your Google Account [jijosanthigiri@gmail.com]. Sign in attempt details Date & Time: Friday, October 10, 2014 5:51:05 PM UTC Location: India If this wasn't you Please review your Account Activity page at ************** to see if anything looks suspicious. Whoever tried to sign in to your account knows your password; we recommend that you change it right away. If this was you You can switch to an app made by Google such as Gmail to access your account (recommended) or change your settings at https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps so that your account is no longer protected by modern security standards. . Sincerely, The Google Accounts team

"
My code is as:

```
MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SMTPServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        SMTPServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("7878@gmail.com", "*******");
        MyMailMessage.From = new MailAddress("7878@gmail.com");
        MyMailMessage.To.Add("123@gmail.com");
        MyMailMessage.Subject = "Test Form";
        MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        MyMailMessage.Body = "EMail Neocon";
        SMTPServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        SMTPServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        SMTPServer.Port = 25;

        SMTPServer.EnableSsl = true;


        try
        {
            SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage);
            lblstat.Text = "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

I googled the error, but didn't a perfect solution to penetrate the blocking without entering customer's gmail account. Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried port 465 instead of 25?

Comment: Google wants secure apps to use oAuth 2.0 to authenticate. You can allow less secure apps to work though by going here: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Icemanind, i can't do changes in customer's mail settings. Because, anyone can register through my webapplication.....

Answer (score 0):

Try removing where the SMTP port is set. SSL does not use Port 25.

'SMTPServer.Port = 25;

Thanks

Comment: I gave : SMTPServer.Port = 587; SMTPServer.EnableSsl = true;

Comment: I believe Google uses port 465 for SSL

Answer (score 0):

I had also problem with sending mails from Gmail. And I found that library System.Net.Mail doesn't support SSL. To resolve your problem use TLS, for gmail it is port = 587

Comment: I used port =587, but now it raising error as StartTLS command first. How to do it in C# code ?

Comment: I gave : SMTPServer.Port = 587;

        SMTPServer.EnableSsl = true;

Comment: Try Port = 25 and set EnableSsl to false, it also should work.

Comment: Hi Bart, I changed the code as you told. But the error showing as "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. t13sm5585460pbs.4 - gsmtp"